# How to check when an executor has finished running a particular Runnable

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable, future, futuretask

I was looking for a way to wait and be notified when a particular Runnable has finished executing within an executor.

I found a [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#isDone%28%29) that has a method `get`, however, this returns a value. My program does not expect a return value; is there any data structure similar to FutureTask without needing to return a value? Almost like a FutureRunnable?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title mentions an executor but your question does not. Do you start the thread manually or do you use an executor?

Comment: `get` will still block and return `null` if the underlying task is a `Runnable`.

Comment: @assylias I was going to submit the FutureTask in question to an exeuctor

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - the constructor of a FutureTask requires you to give back a return value if you pass in a Runnable so not sure how it would return null ... unless I'm missing something. I could set it to return a NullObject ...

Comment: @Karna The FutureTask is returned by the Executor when you submit a Runnable.

Comment: @Djon, ah that's interesting. In that case, what would the return type of "get" be if I submit a Runnable to an executor?

Comment: @Djon - ah, I think I understand. If I "submit" just a Runnable to an executor, the get() method would return null. If you add this to an answer, I can mark as accepted. I believe I misunderstood the flow of execution of the Executor. Thanks!

Comment: It's a `Future<?>`, I can't explan what it is exactly, but it's what I use.

Comment: The return type of `get` can be anything you choose it to be. You'll get `null`, which is assignment compatible with *all* reference types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#isDone%28%29) is what you need.

The FutureTask is returned by the Executor when you submit a Runnable.

Exemple:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ...
    }
}

ExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<?> submit = s.submit(new Task());
```

Comment: isDone does not wait for the task to be completed. The "get" method does.

Comment: Read too fast, but in that case can't you use this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29 if you're using an Executor, as flav asked.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism (not even theoretically) which would somehow "notify the parent thread" when the task is done. First, the thread from which you `submit` a task can't *post festum* become the parent thread of the *ExecutorService*'s internal thread; and second, if your calling thread isn't specifically dedicated to listening for such events, it can't be "jacked into" from outside, interrupting whatever it is doing, and receive the notification.

With standard Java's *ExecutorService* the API you sadly don't get asynchronous notifications via callbacks; all you get is polling methods and blocking methods.